Should I use internal or external storage to create a csv in my android app which I then want to share via email?
I am working on an app which captures sensor data which I then want to export via a CSV.
I am new to Android and don't know enough yet to decide on the best way to do this. I have also been tripping over permission issues - Which I think relates to not understanding best practice on how I should do it.
I want to share the data for further analysis outside of the devices running the app so that it can be manipulated using Web based applications such as Google, Excel etc.
Thanks
I have tried using Internal and External storage and am tripping over issues with attaching the .csv file to an email due to various types of lack of permission exceptions.
I would like to capture data (can do this). Write a CSV (can do this). and share the CSV via an intent (struggling) using the Picker so that a user can send it via their chosen email platform.

If the only way that the user should access the CSV is via your app and its send-via-email feature, you can use internal storage (e.g., getFilesDir() on Context) and FileProvider to make it available to the email app. If, instead, you want the user to be able to access the CSV whenever they want, use the Storage Access Framework (ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT / ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument) and let the user decide where to place the content.

Thanks - I will try out the second option as it would be handy to view outside of the app

In my app I use the following code
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)
    // other code
    //
    setExportCsvSearchActivityResultLauncher()


fun setExportCsvSearchActivityResultLauncher() {
    // You can do the assignment inside onAttach or onCreate, i.e, before the activity is displayed
    exportCsvSearchActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        object : ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult?> {
            override fun onActivityResult(result: ActivityResult?) {
                if (result!!.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // There are no request codes
                    val resultData = result.data
                    // doSomeOperations();
                    csvTreeUri = null
                    //
                    if (resultData != null) {
                        csvTreeUri = Objects.requireNonNull(resultData).data
                        val outputFolder = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, csvTreeUri!!)
                        //
                        if ((isStoragePermissionGranted) || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU))
                        // if the version code >= TIRAMISU (version 33 = Android 13)
                        // you don't need to ask for StoragePermission
                        {
                            Images.exporttoCsv(context, realm)
                            // other code
                            assert(outputFolder != null)
                            //
                            try {
                                copyFileFromInternalToSharedStorage(
                                    context,
                                    outputFolder!!,
                                    "images.csv"
                                )
                // other code
                            } catch (e: IOException) {
                                e.printStackTrace()
                            }
                            //
                        }
                        // view the fragment settings initializing MenuSettingsFragment (FragmentTransaction
                        // switch between Fragments).
                        // other code
                    }
                }
            }
        })
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
@JvmStatic
fun copyFileFromInternalToSharedStorage(context:Context, outputFolder: DocumentFile, destFileName: String?) {
    val sourceStream: InputStream = context.openFileInput(destFileName)
    val documentFileNewFile = outputFolder.createFile("text/csv", destFileName!!)!!
    val destStream = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(
        documentFileNewFile.uri
    )
    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    var read: Int
    while (sourceStream.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
        destStream!!.write(buffer, 0, read)
    }
    destStream?.close()
    sourceStream.close()
}

